# Makefile ifeq logical AND

Tags: unix, makefile, gnu-make, gnu, boolean-logic

I would like to check multiple conditions in an `if` loop of GNU make file. Here's an example:

```
ifeq ($(TEST_FLAG),TRUE && ($(DEBUG_FLAG),FALSE))
true statement 
else 
false statement
endif
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: In newer versions of GNU make there's an `$(and ...)` function which can help.

Answer (score 43):

Although Hasturkun's solution will work, I think the idiomatic way to write this is:

```
ifeq ($(TEST_FLAG),TRUE)
ifeq ($(DEBUG_FLAG),FALSE)
# Stuff
endif
endif
```

Comment: you should the else part so the false statement would execute

Comment: I have troubles when outside ifeq has else like : `ifeq() ... ifeq()...endif else ... ifeq()...endif ... endif`. I get error extraneous `else'.

Comment: What if i want to use or ?

Comment: The "false statement" (in the "else" part) would have to be duplicated.

Answer (score 38):

You can use `ifeq` with a concatenation of your values, eg.

```
ifeq ($(TEST_FLAG)$(DEBUG_FLAG),TRUEFALSE)
   do something
endif
```

It's also possible to use the Conditional functions, which are more likely to be useful in a loop (as `ifeq` will probably not do what you expect in a loop, it will be tested exactly once).

Comment: I think the leading space before `TRUEFALSE` _breaks_ the check and it never will work because `ifeq` is very sensitive regarding a leading space. Can you check it and if I am right edit your answer?

Comment: This would give false positives: `make TEST_FLAG=TR DEBUG_FLAG=UEFALSE`, `make DEBUG_FLAG=TRUEFALSE`

Comment: @xtofl: It will, but it's assumed the values are either `TRUE` or `FALSE` and not some mix of the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the false statement after the two endifs:

```
ifeq ($(TEST_FLAG),TRUE)
ifeq ($(DEBUG_FLAG),FALSE)
true statement 
endif
endif
false statement
```