# GNUmake: How can i write multiple checks in single if condition

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to have a if condition in GNUmakefile with logical && operator.

Eg:-

```
    TEST:=1
     LOG:=""
     ifeq ($(TEST) == 1 && $(LOG) == "")
       dosomething
     else
        ....
      endif
```

Can find something @ [Makefile ifeq logical AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451477/makefile-ifeq-logical-and) , it looks ugly way of concatenating the variable and checking the same.. Is there any other nicer way to have a if check for this
?

Comment: @melpomene, I have already gone through the link and also i mentioned above i the query that it wont answer my question.

Comment: Asking a new question just to receive the answer "No." seems like overkill. Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: If there are better answers, they should be added to the original question. If not, this question is pointless.

Comment: If you have a sufficiently new version of GNU make you can use the `$(and ..)` function: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html

Comment: But in this situation your issue is that you want to test if `LOG` is the empty string, which is "false" in make.  Unfortunately there's no `$(not ...)` in make so you'll have to do a bit of boolean magic.